# Adding AllowAnyHeader does not allow all headers in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-3.1

In my .NET Core 3.1 Startup program, I have something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
    });
}
```

I was expecting that `AllowAnyHeader` would add `"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS";` to the response header, but when I call a DELETE in a method configured with `[HttpDelete]` in the Controller, I see the following in the response header:

`access-control-allow-methods → GET` (no DELETE or OPTIONS)

So, what should I do to see all methods allowed in the response header?

Comment: Hi @ribs, Do you run this project in your localhost or in IIS? I try your code and it works all fine. Do you have another policy in your project? I think It  maybe something wrong in your configuration. So i suggest you to try to specify a policy like this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) instread of using `AddDefaultPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead in Configure

```
app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
```

or you should use

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddDefaultPolicy(
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

then use it in Configure

```
app.UseCors();
```